# Сборка только одной программы из всех

Tags: makefile

Использую autoconf и automake, есть 2 программы в Makefile.am `bin_PROGRAMS = game dedicated`
Как их собрать по отдельности? Например мне нужно собрать только dedicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это превратится **targets** для **make**. После `./configure` можно сделать `make game` или `make dedicated`.

Comment: Хм, проверял перед созданием вопроса, не работало, сейчас попробовал ещё раз, только уже  из директории с исходным кодом этих програм , а не из корня проекта, работает, спасибо.